# Is a std::vector thread safe for my purpose?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 2 threads, only 1 one of them is writing in my vector while the other is just reading. I make sure there is no reallocation by reserving more than needed. Yet I have segfaults and my program doesn't terminate. My vector is the only thing shared, so my question is a std::vector thread-safe for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Reserving is not enough: when you insert, reallocations don't happen, but the value of `end()` and `size()` still changes. Which makes it possible for the reader and writer to race on the value of `end()` or `size()` (whether used explicitly by you, or internally by the vector itself).